# DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique. Line5 This is the error i have tried writing the code multiple times yet not solved plshelp me

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT

pragma solidity  ^0.8.0;

import "./SimpleStorage.sol";

contract StorageFactory{
SimpleStorage[] public SimpleStorageArray;

    function CreateSimpleStorageContract() public {

       SimpleStorage simpleStorage  = new SimpleStorage;
       SimpleStorageArray.push[simpleStoarge];  
    }


}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and share the imported `SimpleStorage.sol` file as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo which might be the cause of the error

```
SimpleStorageArray.push[simpleStoarge];
```

should be

```
SimpleStorageArray.push[simpleStorage];
```